# I've increased the size of image in picture box but now I want to take it back to its original size

Tags: vb.net

I am working with vb.net and want to increase the size of image when the cursor is over that image, but the image should come back to its original size when the cursor leaves that image area.

I've used the following code to increase the size of image:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseHover
    PictureBox1.Size = New Size(300, 250)
End Sub
```

I've used the default size class but, it gives some different dimensions.

Please guide me by the code that brings the image into its original size that I've been declared into the picture box properties.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be hooking in to the [`MouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) and [`MouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) events. Links for MSDN reference

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code that will resize the PictureBox to the dimensions of the image:

```
PictureBox1.Size = PictureBox1.Image.Size
```

Assuming that the original size of the PictureBox was the image size, then that'll work just fine.

As kaveman suggested, MouseEnter and MouseLeave would be much better events to put the code in ;-)

In order to restore the custom size you've set it to, you'll need some code like this: (make sure its somewhere which won't go out of scope, like in the form, outside of methods)

You'll need a variable to store the original size:

```
Dim OriginalSize as Size
```

Then, before changing the size when the user moves the mouse over the image, store the size in the variable: (put this in the `MouseEnter` event)

```
OriginalSize = PictureBox1.Size
PictureBox1.Size = New Size(300, 250)
```

Restoring that size is a simple matter of putting that variable back into the picturebox size: (this goes in the `MouseLeave` event)

```
PictureBox1.Size = OriginalSize
```

=)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable response.. But sir one query is still clicking my mind, i want to re size that image into the size that is been declared into the size property of that image.  Please guide me with the code that will bring back the image into the size that is declared into the property window.. Thank you

Comment: @Omkar: In order to do that, you'll need to store the original size into a global or static variable before changing the size of the image. You can then use that variable to restore the original size =)

Comment: @Omkar: I've added some more code to my answer above, I hope that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @ William Lawn Stewart : It worked dude. Thanks a lot for the help.. Really its awesome. once again thanks a lot. :-)